# Split list until the next largest number with repeat

Tags: python, list, split

Python coding

i want to split list shown below

`a=[5,4,2,5,7,5,4,10,2]`

if this list is given, i want to split it into

`b=[[5,4,2,5],[7,5,4],[10,2]]`

the algorithm is split until there is bigger number than 5 then 5,4,2,5 is in one list,
next number is 7, so split the list until there is bigger then 7 which is 10.
how can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
arr = [5,4,2,5,7,5,4,10,2]

current = arr[0]
temp = []
res = []
for num in arr:
    if num > current:
        res.append(temp)
        current = num
        temp = []
    temp.append(num)
res.append(temp)
print(res)
```

Prints:
`[[5, 4, 2, 5], [7, 5, 4], [10, 2]]`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
a=[5,4,2,5,7,5,4,10,2]

def split(values, threshold):
    splitted = [[]]
    for i in range(len(values)):
        if values[i] > threshold:
            threshold = values[i]
            splitted.append([])
        splitted[-1].append(values[i])
    return splitted

print(split(a, 5))
```

Output:

```
[[5, 4, 2, 5], [7, 5, 4], [10, 2]]
```

Test it [here](https://tio.run/##XY/NCsIwEITveYo9JrCKrRZBqC8ScghkawMhDWla8Omj/UfntMx8s8uGd2o7f81Z17LCG5ZY4R2nqbhgqRgz1EAfnE181G6gHiG1kfq2c0Y8GHw1p4kM1CClUrPXdBEsWA9R@xdxR36ti7U0yTawmNIqeB57D2LSbtcH/QNs9886BPKGSyXYfyZPhdryfcuCRUpD9DvJWIjWJ778rBEqIXL@AA)